# Sorting of some strings?

Tags: php

I can only imagine that this is fairly simple, and yet the solution eludes me.

Let assume I have the following variables:

```
$group1 = "5";
$group2 = "1";
$group3 = "15";
$group4 = "3";
$group5 = "7";
$group6 = "1";
$group7 = "55";
$group8 = "0";
$group9 = "35";
```

I want the groups listed with the highest amount first e.g.:

```
Group 7 is number 1 with 55.
Group 9 is number 2 with 35.
Group 3 is number 3 with 15.
Group 5 is number 4 with 7.
Group 1 is number 5 with 5.
Group 4 is number 6 with 3.
Group 2 is number 7 with 1.
Group 6 is number 8 with 1.
Group 8 is number 9 with 0.
```

Perhaps it would be easier to list all the data in a double-array and then sort it?

Comment: variables with numbers are almost always a sign for bad code. Use an array instead (no "double array", whatever you meant with that).

Comment: Thank you all for the many answers, but I get the feeling that some of you are missing that fact, that the groupID needs to follow the number. Listing all the numbers without the corresponding group would be meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use arrays(just usual arays).

If you array is

```
$group = array(1 => 5, 2 => 1 ... )
```

You may use `arsort` function.

Here I use numbers, not strings. If you will use strings (for values) you need a flag for sort (`SORT_NUMERIC`)

More information in [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php)

Then use `foreach`

```
foreach($group as $key => $value){
    $key is number of varaiable
    $value is value of it.
    you also may add counter to print 1,2,3...
}
```

Comment: +1 for using the appropiate sort function. But you also forgot the sort flag: `SORT_NUMERIC`

Comment: This would be the most straightforward solution - but don't forget that if you use strings for the values then the sorts will be string, not numeric based. You'll want to cast the values to a numeric type before you try and sort using them. :)

Answer (score 1):

use arrays for this purpose

```
$group[1] = "5";
$group[2] = "1";
$group[3] = "15";
$group[4] = "3";
$group[5] = "7";
$group[6] = "1";
$group[7] = "55";
$group[8] = "0";
$group[9] = "35";
```

and then sort it.

```
arsort($group, SORT_NUMERIC);   // SORT_NUMERIC suggested by **fab**
```

Comment: +1 for using the appropiate sort function. But you also forgot the sort flag: `SORT_NUMERIC`

Comment: $group would be overwritten with a boolean in this case, sort functions simply sort the array and return true or false

Answer (score 1):

Just have your data inside an associative array, and sort it with an association aware sort:

```
$groups = array(
'group1' => "5",
'group2' => "1",
'group3' => "15",
'group4' => "3",
'group5' => "7",
'group6' => "1",
'group7' => "55",
'group8' => "0",
'group9' => "35",
);

arsort($groups);

// iteration as usual
foreach ($groups as $group_name => $value) {
}

// getting elements with the array functions based around the array's internal pointer
reset($groups); // reset the pointer to the start
print key($groups); // the first element's key
print current($groups); // the first element's value
next($groups); // moving the array to the next element
```

Comment: This makes the most sense to me, as the groupID follow the number, but how do I "access" an associative array? Lets say the array is sorted like done here, and I just wanted to print the group with the highest number. Normally I would use something like $group[0] assuming the array was sorted, but with an associative array I do not have a starting point to target. Or do I?

Comment: There's a bunch of functions based around the internal pointer of the arrays like `key`, `current`, `reset`, `next` etc. Those can help if you don't want to simply iterate trough the array with foreach. Added some example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using an array is the best thing to do.
something like that

```
$group[1]="5";
$group[2]="1";
```

After that you can sort your array

Answer (score 0):

Put your groups in an array

```
$groups = array("5","1","15","3","7","1","55","0","35");
arsort($groups); //This sort the array is descending order

var_dump($sorted_groups);
```

To print the array in your format use the following function

```
count = 1;
foreach($groups as $key => $value) {
    echo "Group ".($key+1)." is number ".$count++." with ".$value;
}
```

Comment: arsort returns a boolean so do not assign to a new variable

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with an array and `arsort`. This will keep your indexes intact.

`arsort` returns a boolean so do not assign to a new variable

```
$groups = array("5","1","15","3","7","1","55","0","35");
arsort($groups, SORT_NUMERIC);

$i = 1;

foreach ($groups as $key => $val) {
    echo 'Group ' . $key . ' is number ' . $i . ' with ' . $val;
    $i++;
}
```